# socat two serial port together

Tags: linux, unix, socat

I am writing a JUnit test to test my application. The application is written in Java and uses the purejavacomm library. To test the serial parser I want to setup a virtual serial port so the test can communicate with the parser. In addition to simply parsing, it also dynamically connects to the serial port when it becomes available so I do not want to use, say a `PipedInputStream`.

This library only looks for device files that start with `ttyS`, `ttyUSB`, or `ttyACM`. Because of this, I cannot do the regular (which would produce serial ports in `/dev/pts/x`):

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

I tried doing:

```
socat /dev/ttyS20 /dev/ttyS21
```

but it doesn't work. It doesn't exit, or print an error. I tried connecting to `/dev/ttyS20` with screen, but it just says, `[screen is terminating]`.

I looked at the user permissions for `ttyS20` (and 21), and they both have the group, `dialout` (user: root), which my user is in (chris).

Am I overlooking something with the permissions? Is there a better way to do this all together?

Comment: If I was running as root (which a test doesn't), I would be able to symlink the `pty`s to the `ttyS`s. I assume that is what the `link=` flag does though right?

Comment: Can't you simply [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) the purejavacomm classes?

Answer (score 5):

Then what I would suggest is to create a dev folder in your home directory and point the links there.

```
socat pty,raw,echo=0,link=/home/user/dev/ttyS20 pty,raw,echo=0,link=/home/user/dev/ttyS21
```

You should be able to access that without root.  If it is a unidirectional communication I usually like to add the -u option.

Comment: I cannot create a dev folder in the home directory, this is because the library only searches for stuff in /dev.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to link the newly created ptys to another location

```
socat -u -u pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyS20 pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyS21
```

After you create the virtual ports with socat, try changing the ownership of both ends of the pipe to allow easier access.

```
sudo chown user:user /dev/ttyS20
sudo chown user:user /dev/ttyS21
```

You could also change the permissions with chmod to 777.

Comment: I do not want to use `sudo` because that requires root access. I don't want my test to be running as root. The test is going to be binding these serial ports as part of the test.

Comment: The simple fact that the serial ports have the group `dialout` should be enough to link them together I would think...

Comment: Can you have the ports already set up? Or does their creation have to be part of your test?  I have several systems where the OS creates virtual com ports at boot and then applications with normal user permissions use them.  Your test wouldn't need to have root permissions that way.
I am sure some may frown upon me, but for this sort of thing I usually write a script and then stick it in /etc/rc.local.

Comment: The creation has to be part of the test, this simulates the hardware being connected to the computer.