# USB-Serial communication not working on Linux (Bill Validator GBA ST2)

Tags: linux, usb, usbserial

I am trying to communicate with a GBA ST2 Bill Validator using a USB-Serial connection. Everything works fine on Windows (the device is then attached to a COM port) but not on Linux (so far with Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 and Debian 8).

By default the *cdc_acm* drivers are used it is attached to /dev/ttyACMx, but it does not answer any request. (However when requested while in sleep mode it wakes up instantly).

Related output of *dmesg* and *lsusb*:

```
$ dmesg
[26600.821389] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 37 using ohci-pci
[26601.307233] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=16f9, idProduct=0003
[26601.307237] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[26601.307239] usb 2-1: Product: GBA ST2
[26601.307240] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Astrosystems
[26601.307242] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 06010010001
[26601.316173] cdc_acm 2-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device

$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/12p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 37, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 37, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/12p, 480M
```

When forcing the device to use the *usbserial* driver, I was able to use it under a Linux VM (Virtualbox hosted on Windows), but not on a plain Linux machine. I used the following commands to use the usbserial driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r cdc_acm
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x16f9 product=0x0003
```

Related *dmesg* and *lsusb* output:

```
$ sudo dmesg
[26022.203166] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[26022.203188] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.0: Generic device with no bulk out, not allowed.
[26022.206497] usbserial_generic: probe of 2-1:1.0 failed with error -5
[26022.206530] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.1: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
[26022.206532] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.1: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.
[26022.206533] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.1: generic converter detected
[26022.207075] usb 2-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0

 lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/12p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 35, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 35, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=usbserial_generic, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/12p, 480M
```

How can I communicate with this device under Linux? Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: I asked myself the same question. I chose to finally post my question here, as this problem may be related to programmatic aspects (such as the drivers used). I'll try on another better suited place.

Answer (score 0):

depends on what protocol the bill validator uses at the moment, according to http://www.intelligentvending.co.uk/payment-systems-telemetry/banknote-readers-note-stackers/gba-st2.htm it is able to communicate over *ccTalk*, *MDB*, *Parallel*, *Pulse*, *Serial*, *SSP*

you can communicate with a CDC ACM device using `socat`. an example for using `socat` to send AT commands is on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97242/how-to-send-at-commands-to-a-modem-in-linux

`socat` establishes the connection what command sequences you have to send depends on the present protocol of the bill validator...

- http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/33811013/socat-two-serial-port-together